# transfer data between 2 activities in a tab layout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am implementing a fitness app. I have a tab layout for this app, the first tab shows the location(latitude, longitude), speed and other status, and the second tab shows a google map where the running route will be shown as a polyline in the map.

The first tab activity has a location manager that receive the new location.

My question is: how can I transfer the data received from the location manager in the first tab activity to the google map tab activity?

As I know, by using intent.putExtra() and startActivity() can transfer data between 2 activities, but by calling startActivity() I will just immediately go to the map activity right? But I want to update the polyline in the map and stay in the status tab.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Create One `Global class` and `declare static varible` and assign value to it and use another class.
And another way

```
Intent i =new Intent()setClass(this, ListViewerIncompleted.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra(name, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solved this with that code:

in my Login Activity(1st Activity) i need to pass username and Password strings:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            String userName = txtUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = txtPass.getText().toString();
            //instance for UserFunctions.
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(userName, password);
            //Check login response
            try {
                if(json.getString(KEY_REQUESTRESULT)!= null ){
                    txtErrorM.setText("");
                    //Log.e("Passed fine:", "first if condition");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_REQUESTRESULT);//Obtaining the value 0 or 1 from the KEY loginstatus from JSONObject.
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    Intent iii = new Intent("com.mariposatraining.courses.MariposaTrainingActivity");
                    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                    bundle1.putString("UN", userName);
                    bundle2.putString("PW", password);
                    iii.putExtras(bundle1);
                    iii.putExtras(bundle2);

                    //iii.putExtra("userName", userName);
                    //iii.putExtra("Password", password);                       
                    startActivity(iii);
                    finish();
                    //Log.e("OBJECTOO", json.toString());
                }
```

i send this Strings to the TAB HANDLER CLASS and then the activity that manages this information:

```
public class MariposaTrainingActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec ; //recurse to the property tabs
    Intent intent; //intent for open tabs

    //created intent for open the class tab1

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListViewerIncompleted.class); //List 2 Incompleted
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ListViewerIncompleted").setIndicator("INCOMPLETED").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String userName=bundle1.getString("UN");
    Bundle bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String password=bundle2.getString("PW");
    Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
    Bundle bundle4 = new Bundle();
    bundle3.putString("UN", userName);
    bundle4.putString("PW", password);
    intent.putExtras(bundle3);
    intent.putExtras(bundle4);}}
```

in the Class to use this info:

```
 Bundle bundle3 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String userName=bundle3.getString("UN");   //Getting the userName
    Bundle bundle4 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String password=bundle4.getString("PW");
```

Hope this give you ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Use public static variables in your destination Activity to have immediate access to required values from source Activity.